# How do I connect to an Infura web socket in Ethers.js?

Tags: websocket, ethereum, ethers.js

I know in Web3js you can connect to an Infura web socket like so:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<project_id>")
)
```

but how do I connect using Ethers.js? I've tried searching the internet but the answer isn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the [Ether.js docs:](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/other/#WebSocketProvider)

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<project_id>"
)
```

the mainnet is used by default, but you can specify also specify a test network:

```js
// Using a test network
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/<project_id>", "rinkeby"
)
```